# Rails - expand table row on click of link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

in my app that I am building to learn rails and js, I have this case re. to expanding a table row to show a partial. to help understand, see this image:

[image]

The CSS for *edit-tag* can set to display "none"; this is the table:

```
<table id="tags" class="table table-hover" style="background-color: white; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 0.9em;" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Tagged content</th>
        <th>as</th>
        <th>in</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <% object.tags.each do |tag| %>
        <% unless tag.content.blank? %>
        <tr>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= link_to tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch %></td>
            <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
            <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
            <td><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></td>
        <tr id='edit-tag'>
            <td colspan="5"><%= render 'tags/tag_update' %></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
</tbody>
```

I created this function in JS yet it uses ID

```
$(function()  {
var DisplayTagEdit = document.getElementById('DisplayTagEdit');
DisplayTagEdit.onclick = function() {
    var edittag = document.getElementById('edit-tag');
    if (edittag.style.display !== 'none') {
        edittag.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        edittag.style.display = 'block'
    }
}
});
```

So my issues are:

- when creating a JS using an ID (like above) it will relate to all rows in the table. How to make it unique?
- when clicking the link for another row (that is not expanded), the open rows need to be imploded/closed. How to do that?
- may be I am taking a complete wrong approach. If so, let me know how i can make it easier/more simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (including show and hide other rows) generically:

```
$("td.show-tag").on("click", function(event) { 
  var tagId = $(this).data('tagid');
  $('tr.edit-tag').not($('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']')).hide();
  $('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').toggle();
});
```

**Update**

Code above uses display: block
To use display: table-row (to span the row with one td across all columns) use .css()

```
$("#tags td.show-tag").on("click", function(event) { 
  var tagId = $(this).data('tagid');
  $('tr.edit-tag').not($('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']')).css("display", "none");
  $('tr.edit-tag[data-tagid='+tagId+']').css("display", "table-row");
});
```

Yet not yet in my rails view.

### Edit

No need for own JS! Achievable with Bootstap's `collapse.js` applied to the table.

```
<tr id='heading<%= tag.id %>', role="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-parent="tags", class='show-tag', href="#collapse<%= tag.id %>", aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<%= tag.id %>">
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= tag.content %></td>
    <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
    <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
    <td class="delete-btn"><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></td>
</tr>
<tr id='collapse<%= tag.id %>', class='collapse' aria-labelledby="collapse"<%= tag.id %>">
    <td colspan="4"><%= render 'shared/tester' %><%#= render partial: 'tags/update', object: @tag.tagable, tag: @tag %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unique data attribute or class related to object'id to identify them, like:

```
       <tr data-tag-id='<%= tag.id >' class='show-tag'>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= link_to tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch %></td>
            <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
            <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
            <td><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-tag-id='<%= tag.id %>' class='edit-tag'>
            <td colspan="5"><%= render 'tags/tag_update' %></td>
        </tr>
```

And in js(I use Jquery here):

```
  $(".edit-tag").on("click", function(event) {
     var tagId = $(this).data("tagId");
     var $showRow = $("tr.show-tag[data-tag-id=" + tagId + "]"); // here you get the references of the row you need.
     // do want you want ................
     $showRow.toggle();
  });
```

And in Rails, we have "conteng_tag_for", which add the id information to dom element.

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr, tag do %>
     <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><%= link_to tag.content, [object, tag], method: :patch %></td>
     <td><%= tag.tagtype.name %></td>
     <td><%= tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
     <td><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></td>
 <% end %>
```

will generate html like:

```
<tr id='tags_16' class='tags'> <!-- assume tag'id is 16 -->
   <td>......</td>
   <td>......</td>
   <td>......</td>
   <td>......</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: on the content_tag_for ... - are you telling me that I should build up my tables (like in lists) using content_tag_for ? How do I include the fields then (<td> (not good at jQuery yet so bit of help be appreciated :-(  )

Comment: It's just a method may be useful for your need, use or not, it's your decide. I personally don't use content_tag_for much, because it's hard to extract the id information than using data attributes.  I prefer data attributes.

Comment: ok, that is useful to know since I want to use this approach with expanding/collapsing table rows more often! Can you help me a bit with the JS/JQuery - I know a bit of JS, not JQuery. Not sure how to take it from here. be very appreciated.

Comment: tx; have it in my application.js but doesn't function; chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125892/discussion-between-lei-liu-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).

Comment: lei liu - see my JQuery below. It works generically, yet not in my rails view. Any clue as to why?